# How to export joined feature classes without losing field name?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins

I want to export a feature class uisng arcpy that join with other feature class.I use the below code to join and export feature class. The problem is that field names of  the result feature class have change, for example the field name must be "junction" but it changes to "schema_junction". I don't want to lose the names. Is that any solution to maintain the names?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace =r"D:\gisdata\test.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput ="True"
fcp = "primary"
fcs  = "schema"
fclyr=arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fcp,"fclayer")
fcjoin=arcpy.AddJoin_management(fclayer,"code",fcs,"code")
fccopy=arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fclayer,"result")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, set the [qualified field names environment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000008000000) variable to False under your overwriteOutput:

`arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False`